# Java record not saving in mysql database with yellow line

Tags: java, mysql

I was working on a simple java application to save into mysql database. It was working fine until a yellow line began showing on some of my codes. Then records couldnt save in database again which was saving earlier.

Then the "con" and "Exception" starting showing a yellow error line. The error code says i should use "try" on the connection, i did and still didnt work. Please help out. Thanks

My code:

```
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        String sql = "insert into biodatum " + "(firstname, lastname,       address, occupation, phone, email, image, gender, religion)"
        + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        //InputStream is  = new FileInputStream(new File(s));
        pst.setString(1, firstname.getText());
        pst.setString(2, lastname.getText());
        pst.setString(3, address.getText());
        pst.setString(4, occupation.getText());
        pst.setString(5, phone.getText());
        pst.setString(6, email.getText());
        pst.setBytes(7, image_person);
        pst.setString(8, gender.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.setString(9, religion.getSelectedItem().toString());



        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Saved");
        firstname.setText("");
        lastname.setText("");
        address.setText("");
        occupation.setText("");
        phone.setText("");
        email.setText("");
        image_path.setText("");

        pst.close();
        con.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: "A yellow line" Do you mean eclipse is showing you a resource warning?

Comment: No, i am using, netbeans IDE, YES, A resource warning

Comment: So it's telling you to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). But if that doesn't fix it, it's your problem is unrelated (obv). It's just cleaner coding, because it guarantees the connection is closed.

Comment: exactly, i did so and its still not saving, just confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is executing your Prepared Statement?

If your code worked before then you have inadvertently deleted something important, like the code line that executes your Prepared Statement, it should have looked something like:

```
pst.executeUpdate();
```

So, your code should look like:

```
..................................
..................................
String sql = "INSERT INTO biodatum " + "(firstname, lastname, address, occupation, phone, email, image, gender, religion) "
        + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, firstname.getText());
pst.setString(2, lastname.getText());
pst.setString(3, address.getText());
pst.setString(4, occupation.getText());
pst.setString(5, phone.getText());
pst.setString(6, email.getText());
pst.setBytes(7, image_person);
pst.setString(8, gender.getSelectedItem().toString());
pst.setString(9, religion.getSelectedItem().toString());
pst.executeUpdate();  // ************ HERE ***************
..................................
..................................
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's true, i think i mistakenly deleted that line.

Comment: It happens from time to time ;)